# How to do a NATURAL JOIN with a Select subgroup? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, inner-join

I'm trying to get the clients that have made a purchase more than 3 times, and paid cash.

This is my query:

```
SELECT CODIGOCLIENTE, EMPRESA FROM clientes NATURAL JOIN pedidos
                                            NATURAL JOIN
                                             (SELECT COUNT(pedidos.CODIGOCLIENTE), pedidos.CODIGOCLIENTE 
                                                 FROM pedidos
                                                 GROUP BY pedidos.CODIGOCLIENTE
                                                 HAVING COUNT(pedidos.CODIGOCLIENTE)>=3
                                             ) 
                                            WHERE pedidos.FORMAPAGO = "CONTADO"
```

The Select subgroup query does return what i want, which is a table with 2 attributes: COUNT(pedidos.CODIGOCLIENTE) and CODIGOCLIENTE.

So if the foreign key that they have in common is CODIGOCLIENTE, why can't i use a NATURAL JOIN?

It gives me a syntax error on: 'WHERE pedidos.FORMAPAGO = "CONTADO" LIMIT 0, 25'

This is an example of my table clientes:

```
CODIGOCLIENTE | EMPRESA    | 
CT01          | Moderna    | 
CT25          | Jugueteria |
CT04          | CasaTia    |
```

This is an example of my table pedidos:

```
CODIGOCLIENTE | FORMAPAGO
CT01          | Tarjeta
CT15          | Tarjeta
CT25          | Contado
CT25          | Contado
CT25          | Contado
```

So in my result, if the query worked, i would get this:

```
CODIGOCLIENTE | EMPRESA
CT25          | Jugueteria
```

Because it has made a purchase or "pedido" 3 or more times, and he used the method "Contado" to pay

Comment: Your immediate issue is that the subquery needs an alias. But even so, I suspect that your query could be optimized. Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: @GMB ok i just edited it, i tried giving it an alias too but it doesn't work

Comment: Can I suggest never again using NATURAL JOIN?

Comment: @Strawberry haha ;p whyyy.. sorry i'm new doing queries lol.. Is it because it's hard to read for someone who doesnt know the attributes of the tables?

Comment: Avoid natural joins like the plague. They are obscure, error prone, and difficult to debug.

Comment: There's a practical reason to avoid `NATURAL JOIN`. It always joins two tables on _all_ columns that exist in both tables. But it's a common convention to put a `created_at` and `updated_at` column in most tables. The values in these tables is almost never going to match, so your `NATURAL JOIN` will not return any results.

Comment: Even if your tables don't have such columns today, how can you be sure that the tables won't be altered later, and a new column be added to one or both tables with the same name, so your joins that worked before no longer matches anything? You'd have to do a thorough code search anytime you add a column to any table, to make sure you aren't going to spoil any cases of `NATURAL JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select c.*
from clientes c
where (
    select count(*)
    from pedidos p
    where p.codigocliente = c.codigocliente and p.formapago = 'Contado'
) >= 3
```

You *can* also do this with join, although I prefer the first option. I generally do not recommend natural joins, because I find that is not self-explanatory (you need to know the structures of the table to understand which columns come into play in the join):

```
select c.codigocliente, c.empresa
from clientes c
inner join pedidos p using (codigocliente)
where p.formapago = 'Contado'
group by c.codigocliente, c.empresa
having count(*) >= 3
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, it only returns one row, and it's supposed to return like 6 results

Comment: @le0nicolas: both queries would generate the result you expect for your sample data, so as far as I can tell this answers the question you have asked...